Impact of PhD University Reputation on Professor Applications in India?
How important is the reputation of the university where I obtain my PhD when applying for postdoctoral positions and professorships in India? Specifically, how does the ranking and prestige of my PhD institution impact my chances of securing these roles?
I am aware of this question, but I am asking specifically about hiring for faculty positions in India. In particular, if I do my PhD abroad, it seems unlikely that Indian faculty will be familiar with the nuances of the foreign university rankings (outside of the top few departments). And the rankings generally may be more or less important than they are in the US.
My situation is that I might be doing my PhD at a lesser-known university. It seems like a wonderful environment and I am excited about it, but I do not want to doom my chances for a professorship.

Hi @ARa: I took a stab at rewriting your question. I understand the new version isn't exactly what you originally asked, but I think this version is an on-topic, interesting question. If you're OK with this version, let me know and I'll re-open the question. If you don't like this version, we can roll back my edit and let the re-opening process play out democratically (but I think it's unlikely to be reopened in that state).

@cag51 Thanks for the update! This version makes more sense, and is mainly what I want to know. Appreciate the help!

The reputation/ranking of the university where you do a PhD is quite important, especially for faculty/post-doc hirings in the IITs and NITs.
However this is not the only criteria. For eg - an application with PhD from a lesser-known university but a very good publication record would typically not be filtered out.
Initial filtering of applications is usually done by faculty in the same department, so they are expected to be somewhat familiar with top institutes/departments in your area of research.
In summary: If your PhD is from a world-famous institute, it will significantly improve the chances that your application isn't filtered out. If your PhD is from a lesser-known institute, you will need to have a strong publication record and good references.
